# APR thread pool - Getting threads exit codes

Tags: c, multithreading, threadpool, apr

I'm using the APR thread pool (for portability) and I'm trying to get the threads exit codes, because I want to close the whole program (When there are specific error codes).

I noticed that there's no APR function that can access the threads individually from the pool, and there's no APR functions that "joins" the threads in the pool.

The **question** is, how can I **wait** on the thread pool and **get** the threads exit codes when at-least one of them is finished (Using the APR library)

Comment: Hmm, no, the point of a thread pool is that the threads do not exit.  They get re-used.  So of course there is no exit code to look at.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: But what happens if one of the threads fail, how can I know that it failed (except for signalling an event to the whole program)? because checking the actual exit codes seems to be much more cleaner